# Regex keep unique lines

Tags: regex, unique, pcre

Given this string:

```
abc quantity
abc quantity

abc quantity
abc quantity
abc quantity    id
abc quantity
abc quantity
```

I am looking to keep only the unique lines, as in:

```
abc quantity
abc quantity    id
```

So far, I have `(?s)^(.*)(\r?\n\1)+$` and replacing with `$1` as in this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QyXjYl/1)
This is not quiet producing the desired results
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you replacing? Can't you just match the unique lines with `(?m)^(.*)$(?!(?:\R.*)*?\R\1$)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ur4SJR/2))?

Comment: Right, I see the match. How do I keep the matching ones and remove the others?

Comment: Just extract them and join later.

Comment: If preferred you could use a *positive lookahead* and replace matches with empty strings: `(?m)^(.*\R)(?=(?:.*\R)*\1)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/). Whether you do that or join matched lines, however, using a regex would be painfully inefficient if the string were large. Better, as @Aleks suggest, would be to split the string into lines and add those to a set.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is just split the string at `\n`(new line) and push it to set.

Comment: Good advice, but as the OP is asking for a regex solution I think your answer should be a comment.